# Caller cannot see the char array string returned from a function

Tags: c

I am returning a char pointer from a function. But the caller is unable to see the string.

```
char* getFileContent(char* file)
{

FILE* fp = fopen("console.txt", "r");

fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
size_t sz = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);


char* message = (char*)malloc(sz+1);
char buf[sz+1];

size_t len = 0;
if (fp != NULL)
{
    len = fread(buf, sizeof(char), sz, fp);
}

printf("MALLOC SIZE:%d FILE SIZE:%d", sz, len);

strcpy(message,buf);    //Modified code. This line fixed the code
message[++len] = '\0';
//printf("MESSAGE:%s", message);

return(message);

}
```

This is the caller. Output is empty.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{

char* msg = getFileContent(imagefile);

if(msg != NULL)
    printf("Output:%s \n", msg);

free(msg);

return 0;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the output of your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
printf("Output:", msg);
```

You're not printing the string. Try this instead:

```
printf("Output: %s", msg);
```

The `%s` is needed to tell `printf()` to print `msg` as a string.

---

Note that due to buffering, you may also need to add a `\n`:

```
printf("Output: %s \n", msg);
```

---

Here's another minor error:

```
message[++len] = '\0';
```

should be:

```
message[len] = '\0';
```

Comment: Still output is empty. But, if I do strcpy in the function, it is coming in the output. But file contents are not.

Comment: Did you try adding the `\n` into the `printf()`. I edited this into my answer a minute later, so you may have missed it. Other than that, I don't see anything else wrong with the code - unless the file has a null character somewhere in the beginning.

Comment: If I modify the code like this, it works.
`char* message = (char*)malloc(sz+1);
    char buf[sz+1];

    size_t len = 0;
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        len = fread(buf, sizeof(char), sz, fp);
    }

    printf("MALLOC SIZE:%d FILE SIZE:%d", sz, len);
    strcpy(message,buf);`

Comment: @cppcoder Can you edit your question to include the exact current code in your program (including the changes suggested by Mysticial), and the exact output that you get?

Comment: One more small mistake I found: `message[++len] = '\0';` should be `message[len] = '\0';` I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: I have updated my code in the question and it is working.
Any idea why strcpy has fixed the issue and why fread is not?

Comment: @cppcoder By the way, you also need to add the `\n` to your `printf` which prints out the file size; as Mysticial mentions, if you don't add the `\n`, it may not print out because of buffering (`printf` fills up a buffer with text, and only outputs it when it gets to a newline).

Comment: There should be no reason at all for `strcpy()` to make a difference.

Comment: I added `\n` and still it did not print anything.

Comment: @cppcoder The code in the question currently should not be working, because you did not fix the `printf` as Mysticial mentioned; you did not add the `%s` or the `\n` to the format string. In order for us to help you, you will need to put the *exact* code that you are running, and what the output is, otherwise it's very hard to tell what is actually going on.

Comment: @BrianCampbell I updated the code. But without `\n` also it is printing the output.

Comment: I just tested the code without the `strcpy()` and with all my changes and it works. (in VC2010) So I'm not sure what else is causing (what appears to be) undefined behavior in your case.

Comment: @Mystical  My mistake, its working now without `strcpy()`
Thanks.

Comment: @cppcoder So if you go back to your original definition of `getFileContent`, but leave the changes to `main` suggested by Mysticial, it doesn't work? That's fairly surprising to me; all you are doing is reading into a different buffer, then copying that into the buffer that you return. Now, from what I understand, the code in the question now is the working version. Can you post the non-working version, in which you don't use `strcpy` and `buf`, as well? **edit**: Ah, looks like you've gotten it sorted out then.

Answer (score 0):

```
strcpy(message,buf);    //Modified code. This line fixed the code
message[++len] = '\0';
```

I'm not sure if it is guaranteed that after the allocation of the buffer buf it is nullified. Therefore buf[len] might not be '\0' after reading and if there is no '0\' in the read text then your strcpy might run outside its bounds. So either use strncpy or change the above two lines into

```
buf[len++] = '\0\;
strcpy(message,buf);
```

Also the first version places the '\0' at len+1 which in my opinion is false. Imagine you've read 0 bytes then len=0 and message[1] is set to '\0' which leaves message[0] undefined.

Probably your code just ran fine because there is a create change the the allocated buffer buf is either filled with zeros or your compiler actively nullifies it. But as far as I know this is not mandatory for C compilers todo.